# how to use cmake in a virtual environment

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-14.04

I create a virtual environment by Anaconda in Ubuntu 14.04 and installed cmake in this virtual environment. I have installed opengl by apt-get. However, cmake couldn't find the opengl. Do I need to set up some environment variable？

The error output is as followed:

CMake Error at /home/*/.conda/envs/gfb/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:165 (message):

```
  Could NOT find OpenGL (missing: OPENGL_opengl_LIBRARY OPENGL_glx_LIBRARY)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/*/.conda/envs/gfb/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:458 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /home/*/.conda/envs/gfb/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindOpenGL.cmake:433 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:28 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

Comment: "I have installed opengl by apt-get" - What **exact** OpenGL-related packages have you installed? Note, that using some library when building a program usually implies appropriate `-dev` package to be installed.

Comment: I have installed "libegl1-mesa-dev" and "libgl1-mesa-dev"